# Test-Path throws error for file with multiple periods in name,

Tags: sql-server, powershell

When I use the following to check if the DB exists using PowerShell throws an error.

```
Test-Path SQLSERVER:\SQL\TestServer\TestData\Databases\Data\Site1.Test.User.Com
```

ErrorMessage:

> Test-Path : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. SQL Server PowerShell provider error: The number of keys specified does not match the number of keys required to address this object. The number of keys required are: Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
Test-Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL\TestServer\TestData\Databases\\Data\Site1.Test.User.Com"
```

or

```
Test-Path 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\TestServer\TestData\Databases\\Data\Site1.Test.User.Com'
```

**Edit**
The issue is escaping the periods, as the SQL Server PowerShell provider does not like them. Normally, I would expect weird characters within single quotes to be escaped.

Unfortunately I can't try this on my machine. Here are a few other escape method to try - please let me know if one of these works for you:

```
# I expect the regular PowerShell escape character to work
"SQLSERVER:\SQL\TestServer\TestData\Databases\Data\Site1`.Test`.User`.Com"

# If not, standard SQL syntax
"SQLSERVER:\SQL\TestServer\TestData\Databases\Data\[Site1.Test.User.Com]"

# Hexadecimal periods
"SQLSERVER:\SQL\TestServer\TestData\Databases\Data\Site1%2eTest%2eUser%2eCom"
```

Comment: Using double quote or single quote does not help getting same error

Comment: It is possibly the double bracket in `Databases\\Data`? Or is that intentional?

Comment: Thank you corrected "\\" issue, still getting the same error

Comment: Replacing the period with the Hexadecimal value solved the issue